# Fx file not building "texture object does not have methods"

Tags: shader, monogame

I am trying to build the following fx file but I am getting the error in the title. What's wrong with my file? I switched texture2d to Texture.Sample because texture2d no longer exists. That fixed my first error but now this one appears

```
// Our texture sampler

float SINLOC;

float4 filterColor;


texture Texture;
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Texture>;
};

// This data comes from the sprite batch vertex shader
struct VertexShaderOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
    float2 TextureCordinate : TEXCOORD0;
};

// Our pixel shader
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR
{
    float4 texColor = Texture.Sample(TextureSampler, input.TextureCordinate);


    float4 color;

    if (texColor.a != 0)
    {
        color = float4(texColor.r + (texColor.r - filterColor.r) * SINLOC, texColor.g + (texColor.g - filterColor.g) * SINLOC, texColor.b + (texColor.b - filterColor.b) * SINLOC, texColor.a);
    }
    else
    {
        color = float4(texColor.r, texColor.g, texColor.b, texColor.a);
    }


    return color * filterColor;
}

// Compile our shader
technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_4_0_level_9_1 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

Comment: is `<Texture>` a valid format? I think you should remove the `<>` parts

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a very good reference on the various semantics for shaders in Monogame, but a Texture2D is valid. Here is an example for passing in a texture to the monogame pipeline.

```
Texture2D ScreenTexture : register(t0);

sampler TextureSampler : register(s0)
{
    Texture = (ScreenTexture);
};
```